# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED chrome

Tags: node.js, google-chrome

I have been using chrome to run my nodejs server.js file for the past couple days now and all of a sudden I'm getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on chrome. I've looked at other similar questions and everybody says to just type 127.0.0.1:port#. That didn't work. I also tried deleting localhost on chrome://net-internals/#hsts and restarting chrome to no avail. On the cmd line I'm getting 404 "not found" when I run my nodejs app. Using Windows 10. Any suggestion as to what is going on?

edit:
[network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ef34n.png)

edit2:
[cmd line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hDGC.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You might want to look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This question is difficult to answer because there's not really enough information to diagnose the problem. Try posting some code (ideally, a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Please Give Code Snippet, and also your Browser's Developers tool Screenshot (Console and Network tab) so that we can better assert the problem.

Also are you making sure that your app isn't breaking while serving?
(Remember that browsers by-default send GET requests, so if your app is being route is being served at POST or any other route, it may not work).

Comment: just added the console and network tab to my question

Comment: figured it out. didn't set up the server api right.